# Does Stephen Baxter's Silverhair (Mammoth trilogy book #1) contain maps in any edition?

Tags: novel, stephen-baxter, mammoth-trilogy

I cannot locate my print copy, it's probably in a box in the "closet of doom". But it's the mass market US, and might not be exactly the same typesetting as others.

Archive.org lists several copies, and none of those have a map. However, the second and third books on archive.org have maps, or at least have a barely visible bleed-through of a map (though why they excluded scanning the map page, I have no clue). Their copies of Silverhair do not have a bleed-through that I can see.

Amazon and Barnes & Noble do not seem to have electronic editions available, so as best I can tell this is relevant to print copies only (hardback, trade, and mass market).

Comment: Your comment is flawed.  It says that Silverhair is part of a trillogy, but instead of naming that trillogy it descirbes the vast size of it.